# How do you convert an if else statement into a for loop?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I am creating an if else statement that will determine if a year is a leap year or not. I already coded an if else statement that works but I am not sure which variable will go where into a for loop to make it repeat.

```
if (year%4==0 || year%100==0 && !not)
     System.out.println (year + " is a leap year");

    else
        System.out.println (year + " is not a leap year");
```

How would the for loop look like if I convert it into a for loop? Would the if else statement be inside of the for loop or just taken away from the code?

Comment: What do you mean convert it? Conditional statements are not even remotely related to loops. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you change in the loop? Do you increment the `year`?

Comment: do you want to except a bunch number of years, and print out the result for each?

Comment: The semantics of "if-then-else" and "for-each" are so different that it is not possible to provide any kind of answer that would be satisfactory for a general case.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to to make the if else statement that inserted, repeat it self by asking the user to input another year and then reprinting the results.

Comment: I apologize for the misunderstanding, however, Jainul answered my problem with is case 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For loops are iterative statements that repeat a certain block of code , on the other had, if statements are the conditional statements that perform decision making situations. You cannot go from one to other as just as you can't go from repeating stuff and making decisions in most cases.
However, if you wanna repeat the code block, there are two most obivious things that you wanna do while repeating:

1. either repeat and check for different years; getting the years
   either from the user or from some other source.
2. or repeat the code and check for each consecutive year

In the case 2, you can actually merge some stuff into the for loop

Case 1:

```
for(int counter = 0; counter < n; counter++){
// get year data from the console or from other sources
if (year%4==0 || year%100==0 && !not)
 System.out.println (year + " is a leap year");

else
    System.out.println (year + " is not a leap year");
}
```

}

Case 2:

```
 for (int year = 2000; year <= 2100; year++) {
//checking each year from 2000 to 2100
    if (year%4==0 || year%100==0 && !not)
         System.out.println (year + " is a leap year");

        else
            System.out.println (year + " is not a leap year");
        }
    }
```

There are other possible things to do with loops and conditions as well